# Samsung Galaxy S not displaying contacts, only unknown is shown

Tags: caller-id, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My Galaxy S Duos only shows unknown on the display when I have saved phone book contacts calling me? How and what do I do to get numbers to be displayed?

Comment: See also: [Sony Xperia Z won't name contacts on incoming calls](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46749/16575)

Comment: How are you saving your contacts? For example, if I save on my phone 12345678 and 12345678 calls me is is shown normally, but if I save it as 0123412345678, where 01234 = 0 + operator 12 + local area 34, sometimes it is shown as unknown. I tested it with my two SIM of different carriers and it occurs in different ways for different carriers...

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation I found a fix that works for me.  Use this at your own risk.

First, the summary:  The file */data/misc/rild_ril.clip* is a single byte,
either ASCII '1' or ASCII '0'.  Somehow this value is being flipped from '1' to '0' during low storage space conditions and causes the problem.  The solution is to either edit the file, or just delete it and let it be rebuilt.

The steps to fix this problem on your device without losing any data are as follows:

**Requirements**:
ADB or a terminal/console application.

Steps:

1. Get to a shell prompt.  If you're using ADB, it's `adb shell`.  If you're using a terminal/console app, just launch it.
2. Type `rm /data/misc/rild_ril.clip`.
3. Reboot the phone.

That's it. Please let me know if it works or doesn't work for you.